# How can I get the SSL key for traffic sent from my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, https, packet-sniffers

I am trying to view the SSL requests that an app is making on my iPhone. I have the SSL traffic in Wireshark. However, I need to obtain the key. How can I get this key off my iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using mitmproxy and then following this tutorial:

http://jasdev.me/intercepting-ios-traffic

I can now view all the HTTPS requests from the app.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with Charles proxy instead of Wireshark. It involves connecting my laptop to the internet via wire (not wifi). Then I broadcast a wifi signal from my laptop and connect to it with my iPhone. On the phone I go to settings -> Wifi -> HTTP Proxy and set the server to the ip address for the connection (I got this from the connection details off my laptop). I entered 8888 for the port. I installed the SSL keys by going to the Charles proxy site using my iPhone as detailed below. Sometimes I have to restart Charles for it to work.

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/

Comment: Do you have a windows or macbook computer? I have the option of either